# Syntax error in VB.NET application using SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax-error

Hi I have been learning VB.NET for about a month now. I am stuck on something I get an error message saying
`Syntax error in union query.`

The code in question is this.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
        {
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "C:\Users\Nige\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MS_Access_SimplePassword\bin\Debug\Database1.mdb"),
            .PersistSecurityInfo = True
        }
    LoginForm.txtUserName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text

    If LoginForm.txtUserName.Text <> "" Then

    End If
    'do what you want to do
    lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text
    If lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text Then
        Builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Password", "password")
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With
                {
                    .Connection = con,
                    .CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                   ("SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE number" = '55')
            Identifier,
            UserName,
            UserPassword,
            UserTimer
            FROM tblContacts
                </SQL>.Value
                }
                con.Open()
                Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    Reader.Read()
                    TextBox1.Text = Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString
                    TextBox2.Text = Reader.GetString(1)
                    TextBox3.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
                    TextBox4.Text = Reader.GetString(3)
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above was supposed to when I click button5 search my "ms access database" called "tblContacts" for a row that references the number "55"

If my code looks strange in places it because I am a still on a learning path :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of errors in your code above:

```
Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
{
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
    .DataSource = "C:\Users\Nige\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MS_Access_SimplePassword\bin\Debug\Database1.mdb"),
    .PersistSecurityInfo = True
}
```

That `Path.Combine` with two absolute filename is logically wrong, but, nevertheless it works because `Path.Combine` is able to recognize that the two strings passed are two full filename and thus doesn't try to create an impossible path, but return directly the second string.

From MSDN on Path.Combine

> The combined paths. If one of the specified paths is a zero-length
>   string, this method returns the other path. If path2 contains an
>   absolute path, this method returns path2.

Then, looking at your query, it clearly an invalid text for a select and thus you get the Syntax Error.
This could be the correct way to query the datatable assuming

- You search for a row with a column named 'number'
- This column is of text type text
- One or more rows contains in this column a text equals to '55'

  ```
  Dim sqlText = "SELECT Identifier, UserName, UserPassword, UserTimer " + 
               "FROM tblContacts WHERE number = '55'";
  Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Builder.ConnectionString)
  Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlText, con)
     con.Open()
     Using Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While Reader.Read()
              TextBox1.Text = Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString
              TextBox2.Text = Reader.GetString(1)
              TextBox3.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
              TextBox4.Text = Reader.GetString(3)
         End While
     End Using
  End Using
  End Using
  ```